# Fedora mail does not arrive

Tags: php, sendmail, fedora

I use PHP to send mail on Fedora 36.

```
mail($email, $betreff, $content, $header);
```

However the mail does not arrive.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Check the logs of your MTA.

Answer (score 0):

Check if php successfully transfers responsibility for email delivery.

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message,  $headers)) {
    echo 'email was sent.';
} else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
```

On Linux/Unix php by default sends emails via local MTA/SMTP server.
Check/report which MTA is installed on your system (postfix/sendmail/exim/…).